# Excel VBA - Shapes Textbox OnChange event

Tags: excel, vba, events, textbox, onchange

Can someone confirm if there is an event in VBA for when a textbox drawn from the insert menu in Excel 2010 has changed? I tried `RelevantTextBoxName_Change()`but the sub is not called even though the contents of the textbox has changed.

Its a "Shapes" textbox.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you use [this implementation](https://gist.github.com/sancarn/246c0bbe2c8ec35cb492865a9843e3c6)

---

The above library uses a VBA implementation of what @lbo suggested. It's essentially a way of creating 'fake events' from existing events which already capture the functionality you desire. In this case we use `CommandBars_OnUpdate` event (which appears to trigger whenever shapes are changed / deleted / selected / deselected / created. Then we filter down the on the current state of the excel workbook to try to understand what actually occurred. By detecting the selected object is or was a shape, we can adequately determine if this event is occurring on a shape or not.

```
Public WithEvents bars As commandBars
Public old_selection As Object

Private Sub InitialiseEvents()
  Set bars = Application.commandBars
End Sub

Private Sub bars_OnUpdate()
  'This will call on each user action, here we can check our shapes:
  If DetectShape Then
    'Shape selected and changed event:
    If GetName(old_selection) = GetName(Selection) Then
      Debug.Print "Shape Changed"
    Else
      Debug.Print "Shape Selected"
    End If
  End If

  Set old_selection = Selection
End Sub

Private Function GetName(ByVal obj As Object) As String
  On Error Resume Next
  GetName = obj.Name

End Function

Private Function DetectShape() As Boolean
  On Error GoTo endDetect
    DetectShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Count > 0
endDetect:
End Function
```

Running `InitialiseEvents()` will print `"Shape Selected"` whenever a shape is selected and `"Shape Changed"` whenever a shape **might have changed**. Note I leave detecting whether the shape has indeed changed to you.

Answer (score 0):

The excel object model doesn't have any events to control manipulations with shapes. You need visual studio to make it happen. See this:

[Create new events for shape in Excel](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/CSExcelNewEventForShapes-0e26b1f2)

Comment: For the information of others, this 'event' just hooks the `commandBar_OnUpdate` event. This is akin to polling with VBA directly using a Timer.